# undefined reference in c++ class

Tags: c++, class, reference, undefined

Hello guys so I was trying to implement a stack using two queues, however, I ran into a problem saying that the references to the class my_queue is not defined

the errors are ( i am only including some since all of there are undefined reference)

```
my_stack.cpp:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `my_queue::my_queue()'
my_stack.cpp:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `my_queue::my_queue()'
my_stack.cpp:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `my_queue::my_queue()'
my_stack.cpp:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `my_queue::my_queue()'
/tmp/ccNs1Fuy.o: In function `my_stack::push(int)':
 `my_queue::dequeue()'
```

The code for the my_stack is below. Also I have two header file for my_stack class and my_queue class but I assume there is not mistake in them.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include"my_stack.h"
#include"my_queue.h"

my_stack::my_stack(){
    my_queue q1;
    my_queue q2;

}

void my_stack::push(int n){
    q1.enqueue(n);
}

int my_stack::pop(){
    for(int i =0; i<q1.size()-1; i++){
        int temp = q1.dequeue();
        q2.enqueue(temp);
    }//dequeue every element in the q1 except the last element and enqueue to q2
    int x = q1.dequeue();// dequeue the last item of q1


    return x;
}

void my_stack::is_empty(){
    if(q1.size() == 0){
    std::cout<< "the stack is empty"<<'\n';
    }

    else{
    std::cout<< "the stack is not empty"<<'\n';
    }
}

int main(){
    my_stack m;
    m.push(4); 
    m.push(3);
    int yo = m.pop();
    std::cout<<yo<<'\n';
    m.is_empty();

return 0;
}
```

Thanks guys and sorry for the unorganized question.

Comment: Like it says, there is no definition for `my_queue::my_queue()`

Comment: This is a linker error. How are you compiling your program?

Comment: need to see the header files

Comment: @ooga g++ -o o my_stack.cpp

Comment: @ooga am i supposed to do g++ -o o my_stack.cpp my_queue.cpp?

Comment: Any reason for using two queues, instead of one `std::vector` or such?

Comment: @Deduplicator it is a lab question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we can't see the header files i'm making an assumption here but seeing the comments it seems that your linker error may be due to unimplemented functions.

I assume that your header "my_queue.h" contains declaration and not implementation. What you seem to be missing is the implementation of the functions and that is why you encounter a linker error.
Do you have some my_queue.cpp? If so then you should link it because otherwise your program does not know the functions are implements and yet, it is expected to use them. This is the reason for the linkage error

Comment: Yes I do. Yeah it is just a link error. Thanks for the help